# Kendo grid not showing data only on the initial load, but works fine when stepping through with breakpoints

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

The problem I'm having is exactly what I said in the title. When I step through my application in the debugger it properly sets everything that needs to be set, but when I just let it go through on its own, it never loads data on the initial attempt, but if i go back and click the same thing again, or any thing else that has to send data to this grid, it will forever work. Even if I go to a page that empties everything in the grid and then go back to one that shows data again.

To me it sounds like a timing issue, but using `$timeout()` before the data calls doesn't seem to be working. And I set up a broadcast that should only be called after all the data is pulled in and set, and only then should it go to the code for the kendo grid and start painting it on the page.

Like I said stepping through this code line by line on the initial load of the page, it works exactly as it should and pulls in all data that it needs, but letting it just run without me doing that, it never does.

here is hopefully enough code to go off of.

Here is the code for my grid:

```
$scope.$on('loadRxHistoryGrids', function () {
    console.log('user id of ' + pServ.patientId.get());

    $scope.activeHistoryGrid = {
        pageable: {
            pageSizes: [5, 10, 15, 20],
        },
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            type: 'aspnetmvc-ajax',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: function () {
                        var x = pServ.patientId.get();
                        return "api/rx/ActiveRxHistory/" + pServ.patientId.get();
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                },
            },
            pageSize: 5,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        rxId: { type: "number" },
                        refillsLeft: { type: "number" },
                        shortName: { type: "string" },
                        unitsRemaining: { type: "number" },
                        dispenseRefillQuantity: { type: "number" },
                        description: { type: "string" },
                        shipDate: { type: "date" }
                    },

                },
                data: function (data) {
                    if (data != undefined) {
                        $scope.ActiveHistoryCount = data.length;
                        return data;
                    } else { return []; }
                },
                total: function (data) {
                    return data.length;
                },
            },
        }),
        serverPaging: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        columns: [
            { hidden: true, field: "rxId"},
            { field: "shortName", title: "DRUG NAME"},
            { field: "refillsLeft", title: "REFILLS LEFT", width: "16%", template: '#= (refillsLeft == null) ? " " : kendo.toString( refillsLeft, "n0")#', attributes: { style: "text-align:left" } },// template: '<div style="text-align:left">#= ((unitsRemaining == null) || (dispenseRefillQuantity == null)) ? " " : kendo.toString(unitsRemaining / dispenseRefillQuantity, "n5")#</div>' },
            { field: "description", title: "STATUS", width: "14%", template: '<div style="text-align:left">#= (description == null) ? " " : description#</div>' },
            { field: "shipDate", title: "SHIPPED DATE", width: "15%", template: '#= (shipDate == null) ? " " : kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(shipDate), "MM/dd/yyyy") #' }
        ],
        groupable: false,
        scrollable: true,
        selectable: true,
        resizeable: true,
        sortable: true,
    }
```

Here is the other code where the broadcast is being sent:

```
$scope.$on('loadPatientProfileData', function () {

//A lot of data gets and sets are being done here for other things on the 
//page, all data is being set in the grid datasource itself

    setTimeout(function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('patientProfile-DataPullFinish');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loadRxHistoryGrids');
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Please attach some code

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing what your code is doing